# Connect to private host SSH using Git Bash to deploy, manage, and develop website

Tags: git, deployment, web, web-deployment, git-bash

I need to connect to to my private host account, not on GitHub, or any repo service host, just my own host, so I can deploy and manage my website while having version control set up.

I attempted to follow tutorials online, but none of them showed how to actually connect to the SSH account using Git bash, they only showed the `Git init` part and so on.

The problem is that I couldn't find any actual code to the process, or what files to put where, or which commands to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I managed to get everything done, so here's my step-by-step guide on how to connect to your private host's SSH account, using Git bash, to make a private repository, to deploy and manage your website. ***Please feel free to add or correct anything you think isn't right or needs extra information***

## Creating and getting public and private keys for SSH access

For this step, you need to go over to your host, wherever it may be, mines happened to be FastComet, which provides SSH access (I think most host's do).

If you happen to be using FastComet as well, you can use the following guide to complete this section, and skip to the next section:

[How to Generate and Use SSH Keys](https://www.fastcomet.com/tutorials/getting-started/ssh-access)

But if you're not using FastComet, here's a summary of what you need to do.

1. Find the SSH Access menu in your host control panel.
2. Select to create a new SSH access key.
3. This is likely to ask for:
4. Key Name – The name of the key for internal recognition

   - Key Password – A password to protect the key
   - Key Type – Here you can choose between DSA and RSA
   - Key Size – Choose between 1024, 2048 or 4096bit length
5. You might need to Authorize the key, I had to, but you might not, so look around and see if there's an authorize option in the control panel.
6. Download the private key. (sorry, it's not too specific, but it should be self-explanatory, there should just be a download button next to where it displays the private key)

## Setting up the SSH on Git

So now you have set up the SSH access, you need to actually access it. Normally, you'd just open git bash and enter `ssh username@host.com -p <port>`, then it will prompt you for your password, and you log in, then you are good to go. But if you're like me and don't want to enter your password every time, follow these steps.

1. Open up your `.ssh` folder, usually in `C:/users/YOURUSERNAME/.ssh` (or `~/.ssh`)
2. Paste in the private key that you downloaded from the previous section.
3. Open git bash, you'll need to open up your `.bashrc` file, my preferred text editor is Notepad++, so I've given it an alias in bash as `npp`, so `cd ~` and type into bash: `npp .bashrc`
4. Once you've opened up `.bashrc`, paste the following code into it:

   ```
   env=~/.ssh/agent.env
   agent_load_env () { test -f "$env" && . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }
   agent_start () {
   (umask 077; ssh-agent >| "$env")
   . "$env" >| /dev/null ; }
   agent_load_env
   # agent_run_state: 0=agent running w/ key; 1=agent w/o key; 2= agent not running
   agent_run_state=$(ssh-add -l >| /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?)
   if [ ! "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] || [ $agent_run_state = 2 ]; then
   agent_start
   ssh-add
   elif [ "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && [ $agent_run_state = 1 ]; then
   ssh-add
   fi
   unset env
   ```
5. Now save the file, then `exit` out of git bash, and open it up again. If it asks for any passphrase, enter your passphrase (it probably won't, if it does, it means you had set it up before, so you know what the passphrase is).
6. Type `ssh-add ~/.ssh/FILENAME OF YOUR SSH KEY`

   - Enter your passphrase
7. Done. You have added your SSH private key, to your SSH-agent.

## Deploying your website(files) onto your host

1. Now type `ssh username@host.com -p <port>` and it should not ask you for a passphrase every time.
2. To give credit, where credit is due, I'm going to refer you to these two guides I used to do the purpose of this section.

[Deploying Website with Git {VIDEO}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zvpLDuRY4ss)

[Managing Website with Git {ARTICLE}](http://crosbymichael.com/how-to-manage-your-website-with-git.html)

## Extras

- At the stage of following those two guides in the last section, I faced an issue that you might too:

I couldn't add my host as a remote on git bash, when I used the command `git remote add NAME username@yoursite.com/~/REPO.git`. And it got confusing, because I had to add a port to the URL as well, so it got complicated, but eventually I figured it out.

**Solution:** Make sure you include a `ssh://` before your URL, and if you have a port and a file path like I did, use this format of the command:

`git remote add REMOTENAME ssh://username@host.com:PORT/FILE/PATH TO/REPO.git`